# FloatDomainError (Infinity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I use carrierwave and mini_magick to upload images. In development everything is fine, but in production it raises `FloatDomainError (Infinity)` when i try to upload an image. I have several projects hosted at the same server and everything is fine with uploading. 
I use Rails 3.0.10.
Any ideas how can i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem is `mini_magick`. If the image file it runs `identify` on is erroneous, identify will output some kind of error, e.g.

```
identify: Corrupt JPEG data: 7929 extraneous bytes before marker 0xed `image.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/EmitMessage/230.
11811 8665
```

`mini_magick` tries to parse the error message as the dimension, and the result is `0`. This results in a division by zero which results in the exception you mentioned. This is the reason why it only fails with some images.

`identify` has a `-quiet` options to turn off these warning messages. I have forked mini_magick at https://github.com/fschwahn/mini_magick and added the quiet option. I hope this change will be pulled in (or the problem will be fixed in a more elegant way). However, for now you can use my fork by adding the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mini_magick', :git => 'git://github.com/fschwahn/mini_magick.git'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try your fork asap. In current projects i started using rmagick instead.

Comment: My changes have been pulled and a new version of mini_magick has been released, so if you depend on the latest version of mini_magick the problems should go away.

Comment: Thank you! this helped me with that problem in newest minimagick (3.6.0). I won't use any other version now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed that with replacing `resize_and_fill` to `resize_and_pad`. Still don't understand its strange behavior.

Comment: actually `resize_to_fill` and resize_and_pad` have different effects. replacing one with another is just a way to have your application run at any price.

Comment: Agree. That was a temporary solution just to make it work. Hope that @fabi's solution works now

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Ubuntu Imagemagick package version 6.7. I upgraded to 6.8 following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/267746/how-can-i-install-the-latest-upstream-version-of-imagemagick-without-compiling and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**I got this error with the newest gem update**, when I generated an image thumbnail for my pdf file.

This code fails:

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [260, 192]
  process :convert => :png
  process :set_content_type
  process :thumbnail_pdf
end
```

I solved it by replacing the order of the lines. The key was that before resizing `MiniMagic` should first convert thumbnail to image and after that should try to resize.

**Here is solution** which worked for me. Maybe it'll help for someone.

```
  process :convert => :png
  process :resize_to_fill => [260, 192]
```